# "char inChar = (char)Serial.read();" why is the "char" in brackets? and what is it called

Tags: serial

I am sure this is a very simple answer, but I don't know to look it up on google

In the example "SerialEvent" in the arduino IDE (v1.8.7), there is the following function

```
    void serialEvent() {
        while (Serial.available()) {
           // get the new byte:
           char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
           // add it to the inputString:
           inputString += inChar;
           // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
           // do something about it:
           if (inChar == '\n') {
               stringComplete = true;
           }
        }
     }
```

On the third line "**char inChar = (char)Serial.read();**" the (char) is given in brackets before the serial read. 
Why is this? and more specifically how is called ?

Comment: This is actually more a C/C++ language question. The hint is "Please check the return value type for `Serial.read()`".

Comment: So it basically forces the value returned from serial.read() to be a char? Do you know how this is named, so I can look up the documentation?

Comment: [In C, why are there parentheses around (int) in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30790649/995714), [Type in parentheses in C variable definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34600251/995714)

Comment: What topics can I ask about here? On topic: Specific questions about Arduino boards, code…  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Is this question not a specific question about Arduino code? Voting to not close.

Comment: @will.mendil This is called "Explicit type conversion" or "Casting". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast. In some cases it ends up as some extra code but in other cases it is just a hint to the compiler and no extra code is generated.

Comment: @will.mendil Why is the explicit cast necessary above? What would happen if the statement was `int inChar = Serial.read();`? What would the statement `inputString += inChar;` mean if changing `char inChar` to `int inChar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called type casting and will convert one type to another. The return type of `Serial.read()` is `int`, because it will return `-1`, when you try to read without any bytes being available. The casting with `(char)` will drop the high byte of the (2-byte long) integer, leaving only the lower byte. This byte will contain the actual read data, in which you are interested here.

Casting is a complex thing, because there can be different ways to convert different types (for example maintaining the bit-content vs. maintaining the decimal value). The casting, that you are seeing here, should only be done, if you really know, what you are doing. The bits will not be changed to maintain the correct value, but the bit-content will be preserved, unless the new type is smaller than the former. In this case the rest is lost. Also, if you try to cast a `float` value to an `int` value with this, you will get a totally different decimal value out of it, because the numbers are encoded in the bits in a totally different way. Here it is known to be OK, especially, if you are checking for available bytes before reading with `Serial.available()`, because the library puts the ASCII data in the lower byte.

For further explanations you should consult C/C++ guides.